# insert an exponent of an integral into the integrated function

Tags: integration, exponentiation

Suppose $x$ and $\lambda$ are real number,

Are there any real-valued function $f(x,\lambda)$ and $g(x)$ satisfying following equation?

$\int f(x,\lambda)dx=\left(\int g(x)dx\right)^\lambda$

General condition to satisfy this equation is more helpful.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You're using the letter $f$ for two different things, namely a function of two variables and a function of one variable, unless you meant something else.

Comment: > Reveillark Thank you for pointing out miss terminology. I edited letter $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's actually a surprisingly interesting question.  Here's a way to get started that seems to lead somewhere: first, for convenience, write $ A(\lambda) = \int {f(x,\lambda)dx} $ and $ G(x) = \int{g(x)dx} $.

If you raise both sides to the $ 1/\lambda $ you get $ A(\lambda)^{1/\lambda} = G(x) $.  Now let's differentiate both sides of this with respect to $ \lambda $. 
 Since the right-side doesn't depend on $ \lambda $, we get zero on the right-hand side.  The calculations give you
$$
A(\lambda)^{1/\lambda} \left(\cfrac{A'(\lambda)}{A(\lambda)\lambda} - \cfrac{\log A(\lambda)}{\lambda^2} \right) = 0
$$
One solution of course is $ A(\lambda) \equiv 0 $, but more interestingly, setting the second factor to zero and clearing denominators gives you a nice, separable differential equation,
$$
\lambda A'(\lambda) - A(\lambda) \log(A(\lambda)) = 0
$$
Try going from there.

Comment: Thank you for showing fundamental direction of solution. The solution of differential equation you gave is $A(\lambda) = e^{|\lambda|C}$, where C is a constant. This is very interesting result. Thank you very much!